# Get a list of entities that match ALL the supplied ids for a related entity field in a many-to-many association

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to get a list of users from the database that have ALL the tags in a criteria.

The User entity has a many-to-many association to a Tag entity.

The or version where just one of the tags have to match is working using the following code

```
$tagIds = array(29,30);
$this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('u','t')
    ->leftJoin('u.tags','t')
    ->where("t IN(:tagIds)")
    ->setParameter("tagIds",$tagIds)
;
```

Can anybody help me with getting it to work so ALL tag ids must match ?
Keep in mind this is a query to get a list of users, not just one user , so i guess every user must be checked to see if they match all the supplied tag ids.

I have tried a bunch of queries but not having any luck so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after a lot of searching this seems to work for me :

```
    $tagIds = array(29,30);
    $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u','t')
        ->leftJoin('u.tags','t')
        ->where("t IN(:tagIds)")
        ->groupBy('u.id')
        ->having('COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = ' . count($tagIds))
        ->setParameter("tagIds",$tagIds)
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple bruteforce query:

```
$tagIds = array(29,30);
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb
    ->select('u')
;

foreach($tagIds as $idx => $tagId)
{
  $joinAlias = "t{$idx}";
  $qb->leftJoin('u.tags', $joinAlias)
     ->addSelect($joinAlias)
     ->andWhere("{$joinAlias}.id = $tagId AND $joinAlias IS NOT NULL")
  ;
}
```

this is really bruteforce and costly query, you join each tag as a separate join, if you have lots of users and tags, this will take ages to execute.

since database is the bottleneck of your application, you should make a simple query to the database and then parse the data in your application, so you should use your query and then check which users have those 2 tags in their collections.

Comment: That is pretty interesting, but would that not make pagination very difficult ?